# unable to compile Web service project with VS 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, soap

I try to compile with VS 2008 old C# Service project based on WSE where DIME attachments are used:

The compiler does not find:
      using Microsoft.Web.Services.Dime

I just installed WSE 3.0. Even that does not help to find Microsoft.Web.
What is the replacement for  DimeAttachment class?

thanks Arman

**EDIT**

Well the answer what I marked as a answer is not really related to my problem  but the comments were putting me in to right way.

I just learn from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529283.aspx that WSE3 handles attachments differ and I just migrated few lines to WSE3 and code is running.

Comment: And does that old project have a reference to a m.w.s.DIME assembly? Did you rfresh that?

Comment: Ok I just generated new project from scratch with VS 2008. I was supriced that Dime is not in WSE3, so i just included WSE2.0. It compiles but it asks now for missing HttpSoapContext Where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the required DLL physically present on your disk? If so, remove the reference and re-add it by selecting the DLL that you know is there. If that works, sounds like the original referenced version just could not be located and your [ReferencePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6taasyc6(v=VS.100).aspx) needs fixing.

Comment: Yes the problem was simply to add correct WSE version.I use now WSE2. It compiles but it asks now for missing HttpSoapContext Where is it?

Comment: @Arman - 'In WSE 2.0, however, the HttpSoapContext class has been marked obsolete because the object model has evolved to the point that SoapContext can be used over other protocols in addition to HTTP. Hence, in WSE 2.0 HttpSoapContext has been removed and two new classes named RequestSoapContext and ResponseSoapContext have been added. Each class has a static Current property for retrieving the current SoapContext object as shown in the bottom of Figure 3.' See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163942.aspx for details.

Comment: nice I migrated few lines to WSE3 following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529283.aspx and my code is compiles!!!